# Нужен ли контейнер

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как правильнее будет сверстать навигацию? Если навигация идет с небольшими отступами ≈90% ширины, а дальше по макету уже все идет с определенной шириной. Нужен ли тут контейнер или можно просто задать отступы  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для навигации можно свой контейнер сделать)

Answer (score 0):

Если у хедера при скролле появиться заливка то обернуть, в ином случае можно не оборачивать

```css
header{
  text-align: center;  
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div{
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header>hello</header>
</div>

<hr>

<header>hello</header>
```